# How can I solve this PDE in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, matlab

I got the following equation from physics.

$$C \sin \theta \frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}        \right)$$
where boundary conditions are $T(R,\theta)=T_0, T(\infty,\theta)=0 $ and $C, T_0, R$ are constant.

I would like to find $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}$ where $r=R$ from the equation.

How can I solve this?

If it is impossible, can I get help solving using Matlab or other numerical methods? Thank you so much!

Comment: What are $T_w$ and $T_0$? Functions or constants? What is the domain?

Comment: You can separate variables: $T(r,\theta)=R(r)S(\theta)$, then you get two uncoupled equations for $R$ and $S$. I find that $S$ is a power of $\cot(\theta/2)$ and that $R$ is a Bessel function of order zero

Comment: At $r=R$ the "inner" boundary condition holds and the solution is radially symmetric (as also is the boundary condition "at infinity").  So my first step would be to look for radially symmetric solutions.